# Hide select menu when you make a selection

Tags: jquery

I want the div `#replaced` to disappear upon selecting any option from its select menu. I then want the div `#replacer` to replace it... but I have that part figured out.

I'm wondering what my selector should be so that its only after an option is selected not before. Otherwise the menu disappears before you can select an option (defeating the purpose).

```
<div class="filters" id="limit"> 

    <div id="replaced">
        <select id="mark" name="mark">
            <option value="A"><p>A?</p></option>
            <option value="B"><p>B?</p></option>
            <option value="C"><p>C?</p></option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div id="replacer">
        <select id="series" name="series">
            <option value="Z" class="format"><p>Z?</p></option>
            <option value="Y" class="format"><p>Y?</p></option>
            <option value="X" class="format"><p>X?</p></option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this currently... but it's wrong for what I want

```
$("#replaced").click(function() {
    $("#replaced").fadeToggle(2000);
});
```

How can I make the container disappear when a selection is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.change()`

```
$("#mark").change(function() {
    //replace code
});
```